# how to set timeout for Executors.newFixedThreadPool and create thread once it reach timeout

Tags: java, multithreading

My program should run with multithreads for a really long time.
I need the ability to set timeout for the threads, and once thread is terminated I want to start it again.
here is my code:

```
    @Test
    public void testB() throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        System.out.println("thread start: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        threadPool.awaitTermination(100000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: So what you wanna do is run the same tasks over and over again, until a given timeout is reached?

Comment: yes. and if timeout is reached on one of the thread, then i need to execute another thread. for example - i need 2 to run 2 thread all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will run the same to tasks over and over again.
The pool will be shutdown after a given amount of time.

This seems to do what you requested.

```
final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    final int taskNb = i;
    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread " + taskNb + " start: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Submit same task again
            threadPool.submit(this);

        }
    });
}

// Only shutdown the pool after given amount of time
Thread.sleep(100_000_000);
threadPool.shutdown();

// Wait for running tasks to finish
threadPool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```